# Trying to retrieve data from the Anbima API

Tags: python, api, request

I'm trying to automate a process in which i have to download some brazilian fund quotes from Anbima (Brazil regulator). I have been able to work around the first steps to retrieve the access token but i don't know how to use the token in order to make requests. Here is the tutorial website https://developers.anbima.com.br/en/como-acessar-nossas-apis/.

I have tried a lot of thing but all i get from the request is 'Could not find a required APP in the request, identified by HEADER client_id.'

If someone could share some light. Thank you in advance.

```
import requests
import base64
import json

requests.get("https://api.anbima.com.br/feed/fundos/v1/fundos")

ClientID = '2Xy1ey11****'
ClientSecret = 'faStF1Hc****'

codeString = ClientID + ":" + ClientSecret

codeStringBytes = codeString.encode('ascii')
base64CodeBytes = base64.b64encode(codeStringBytes)
base64CodeString = base64CodeBytes.decode('ascii')

url = "https://api.anbima.com.br/oauth/access-token"
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
    ,'authorization': f'Basic {base64CodeString}'
}
body = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
r = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
jsonDict = r.json()

##################
urlFundos = "https://api-sandbox.anbima.com.br/feed/precos-indices/v1/titulos-publicos/mercado-secundario-TPF"
token = jsonDict['access_token']

headers2 = {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
    ,'authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
}
r2 = requests.get(url=urlFundos, headers=headers2)
r2.status_code
r2.text
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, but today I could advance. I believe you need to adjust some parameters in the header.
Follows the piece of code I developed.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

PRODUCTION_URL = 'https://api.anbima.com.br'
SANDBOX_URL = 'https://api-sandbox.anbima.com.br'
API_URL = '/feed/fundos/v1/fundos/'
CODIGO_FUNDO = '594733'

PRODUCTION = False

if PRODUCTION:
  URL = PRODUCTION_URL
else:
  URL = SANDBOX_URL

URL = URL + API_URL + CODIGO_FUNDO

HEADER = {'access_token': 'your token',
          'client_id' : 'your client ID'}


html = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADER).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

The sandbox API will return a dummy JSON. To access the production API you will need to request access (I'm trying to do this just now).

Answer (score 0):

```
    url = 'https://api.anbima.com.br/oauth/access-token'
    
    http = 'https://api-sandbox.anbima.com.br/feed/precos-indices/v1/titulos-publicos/pu-intradiario'
    
    client_id = "oLRa*******"
    client_secret = "6U2nefG*****"
    client_credentials = "oLRa*******:6U2nefG*****"
    
    
    client_credentials = client_credentials.encode('ascii')
    senhabytes = base64.b64encode(client_credentials)
    senha = base64.b64decode(senhabytes)
    print(senhabytes, senha)
    
    body = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    }
    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic b0xSYTJFSUlOMWR*********************'
    
    }
    
    request = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body, allow_redirects=True)
    informacoes = request.json()
    token = informacoes['access_token']
    headers2 = {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "client_id": f"{client_id}",
        "access_token": f"{token}"
}
    titulos = requests.get(http, headers=headers2)
    titulos = fundos.json()
```

I used your code as a model, then I've made some changes. I've printed the encode client_id:client_secret and then I've copied and pasted in the `headers`.
I've changed the `data` for `json`.

Answer (score -1):

Still not working, had tried several things, and after get the return from AMBINA, need to put in some kind of HTML format.

```
import requests
import base64
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://api.anbima.com.br/oauth/access-token'    
http = 'https://api-sandbox.anbima.com.br/feed/precos-indices/v1/titulos-publicos/pu-intradiario'

client_id = "oLRa*******"
client_secret = "6U2nefG*****"
client_credentials = "oLRa*******:6U2nefG*****"


client_credentials = client_credentials.encode('ascii')
senhabytes = base64.b64encode(client_credentials)
senha = base64.b64decode(senhabytes)
print(senhabytes, senha)

body = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic b0xSYTJFSUlOMWR*********************'

}

request = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body, allow_redirects=True)
informacoes = request.json()
token = informacoes['access_token']
headers2 = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "client_id": f"{client_id}",
    "access_token": f"{token}"
}
titulos = requests.get(http, headers=headers2)
titulos = fundos.json()
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33964920)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).